# Choose c so that f is a density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables, density-function

Let the function f : R→R with c > 0 be deﬁned by 
$$
f(x) :=
\begin{cases}
cx,  & \text{for $0\le x\le1$} \\
cx^2, & \text{for $1\lt x\lt2$} \\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
i. Choose c such that f is a density function.
Ok so here I made the integral of the functions equal to 1. I get 2 values of c. $C= 2$ or $\frac7 3$

Is it normal to have 2 values of C? How do I know which one I should use?

ii. Find $P[X > 1]$ and $P[−1/2 < X < 1/2]$.

again which c or row should I use? and when I integrate, is it$ P[X\gt1]=\int_1^2 (cx)dx? $ And for $P[-\frac{1}{2}\lt x \lt \frac{1}{2}]=\int_{-\frac1 2}^{\frac 12} (cx)dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- You should not have two values of $c$.
- Solve for $c$ in 
  $$c\left( \int_0^1 x\, dx +  \int_1^2 x^2\, dx\right)=1$$
- When $x>1$, use the rule in $1<x<2$.
- $$P(-\frac12 < x< \frac12) = P(0\le x < \frac12)$$

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try it out now! Btw what do you mean by "use the rule in 1<x<2?

Comment: to evaluate $P(X>1)$ use $cx^2$ rather than $cx$.

Comment: So for the last part do I use $cx^2$ or $cx$? How do you know which one to use?

Comment: You are interested in $0 \le x < \frac12$, they are all values which are less than $1$ isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes now i see it. Thanks for your advice!